# Wrong input shape densenet212

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to create grad-cam saliency maps for gray-scale images in DenseNet121. I'm having an issue running my code and can't make my images fit the desired input shape.

That's my code for heatmaps

```
def get_class_activation_map(path) :
    
    img_path =  path 
    img = cv2.imread(img_path)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (150, 150))
    img = np.expand_dims(img,axis=0)
    
    
    predict = model.predict(img)
    target_class = np.argmax(predict[0])
    last_conv = model.get_layer('conv2d_119')
    grads =K.gradients(model.output[:,target_class],last_conv.output)[0]
    pooled_grads = K.mean(grads,axis=(0,1,2))
    iterate = K.function([model.input],[pooled_grads,last_conv.output[0]])
    pooled_grads_value,conv_layer_output = iterate([img])
    
    for i in range(512):
        conv_layer_output[:,:,i] *= pooled_grads_value[i]
    
    heatmap = np.mean(conv_layer_output,axis=-1)
    
    for x in range(heatmap.shape[0]):
        for y in range(heatmap.shape[1]):
            heatmap[x,y] = np.max(heatmap[x,y],0)
    heatmap = np.maximum(heatmap,0)
    heatmap /= np.max(heatmap)
    plt.imshow(heatmap)
```

And the error I get

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected densenet121_input to have shape (150, 150, 1) but got array with shape (1, 150, 150)
```

Can you please tell me how to change my code so that it changes the dimensions itself?

Answer (score 1):

Before performing prediction in line:

```
predict = model.predict(img)
```

Do this:

```
img = np.moveaxis(img, -1, 0)
```

This will reverse the shape from channels_first to channels_last, which is expected in your model.

Comment: I did that, thanks, but now it throws me a different error `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected densenet121_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 150, 150)`. Should I simply expand the dimensions again?

Comment: Your input layer is expecting an array of shape (batch_size, 150, 150, 1).  You can try reshaping your data as follows: 

`img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=-1) `